# Error running Heroku bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I just updated my Gemfile and upgraded to rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0. I ran `bundle install`, `bundle update`, then pushed to Heroku. Then I migrated the db.

The app works on localhost but shows an application error on Heroku.

So I ran `heroku run bundle update`, which gave the following error:

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze 
by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

    You have added to the Gemfile:
    * source: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery (at master)
    * source: rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/
* rails (= 4.0.0)
* sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
* uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
* coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
* jquery-rails
* turbolinks
* jbuilder (~> 1.2)
* sorcery
* thin
* pg
* rails_12factor
* sdoc
* mailcatcher
* rspec-rails
* sqlite3
* foreman
* quiet_assets


You have changed in the Gemfile:
* sorcery from `https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery (at master)` to `no specified source`
```

This is what my .gitignore file looks like:

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global

# Ignore bundler config
.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
db/*.sqlite3
db/*.sqlite3-journal
db/development.sqlite3

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
log/*.log
tmp

.DS_Store
.sass-cache

.ruby-version
Procfile
.rspec
```

The error on Heroku is just a standard "Application error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served."

Here are my [Heroku logs](https://gist.github.com/colmtuite/10b609aefc1c720fa1b6)

Comment: Is your `Gemfile.lock` tracked by git? It should be, and I don't see it in your `.gitignore`, but that's the first thing to verify. Also, what's the application error heroku is throwing? Is it successfully deploying?

Comment: What type of error are you getting on Heroku? If it's a standard Heroku error, it could suggest a `db` connection issue, but from your error, it looks like the `sorcery` gem is causing the problem (says it has no source)

Comment: @agmin How do I track my Gemfile.lock? Where in the .gitignore file should I put it? I'll update the question with the Heroku error.

Comment: @colmtuite if the file doesn't show up as untracked when you run `git status` you're already tracking it.

Comment: It thinks that you have erased a source option for `sorcery` in you Gemfile, while in the Gemfile.lock, there is one specified: `https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery (at master)`. You'll need to figure out why your local installation is finding that source during `bundle update`, while Heroku thinks none is specified.  This might occur if you have used `bundle config` to set a source known only on your local machine.  If that's the case you can fix it by adding the source to your `Gemfile`.